# How to avoid .htaccess constant seek?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Are there any options in Apache 2.4 that enable the .htaccess to be cached, and not having the web server looking for it at each request?

I know that using the AllowOverride None, will do this, but then, for most popular scripts this will need the required settings to be made in the vhosts file for each folder.

If somehow we could just tell Apache to remember the htaccess files that it has already accessed since previous restart, this would be a great tool for speed improvement.

A script that reads the base content recursively for all htaccess, and builds a vhosts file, would not be a bad idea as well, anyone uses this approach?

Comment: *Would* it be a great improvement? Have you measured how long Apache spends parsing that file?

Comment: It is not so much about the file parsing, it is related to the amount of files, not the file content itself, apache for each directory pathname will search if the .htaccess file exists. So if you have content in 5 folders, apache will try to search for the htaccess on each of them, if you have hundreds, the same. On my measurements , I estimate 2ms for each htaccess search.